# how to have a fixed navbar which is visible only when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help me have a fixed top navbar which is invisible initially and comes up when scrolling down. Please refer navbar of http://snowehome.com
I want to have a navbar exactly with the same function as this website.

Comment: What have u tried so far?

Comment: You need to add your own code to show that you at the very least tried...

Comment: jQuery(function($) {
               function fixDiv() {
                var $cache = $('#getFixed');
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50)
                    $cache.css({
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'top': '0px'
              });
                 else
                 $cache.css({
                 'position': 'relative',
                 'top': 'auto'
              });
           }
         $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
            fixDiv();
           });
 I tried this but navbar but navbar not hiding initially.

Comment: See the edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about your progress. You should mention your progress. By the way I did same type of problem a few days ago. You may try it.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($) {
               function fixDiv() {
                var $cache = $('#getFixed');
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0)
                    $cache.css({

                    'display' : 'block',
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'top': '0px'
              });
                 else
                 $cache.css({
                 'position': 'relative',
                 'top': 'auto',
                 'display' : 'none'
              });
           }
         $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
            fixDiv();
           });
    </script>
```

The navbar should be-

```
<nav class="" id="getFixed">
     <!-- your navbar code here. Just focus on the id of nav tag-->
</nav>
```

**Edit :-** add a style in your page

```
<style>
    #getFixed{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: green;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
</style>
```

Now look at the script again.

Comment: your answer is a good idea, but I think you can optimise it by replace the `.css()` by a `.addClass()` and define all the style for the fixed nav bar in your CSS

Comment: It's not a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you Sajeeb but its not hiding initially. I wanted the navbar to be hidden initially just like snowehome.com please refer and help me out.

Comment: add some external CSS for hide it initially. i.e. #getFixed{display:none;}

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the navbar at http://snowehome.com is never hidden. What is happening there is just a navbar, getting displayed through a transition effect and is stick to the top of the page.

Sajeeb Ahamed provided an answer which fits the wished behaviour. Yet, I would also recommend using `.addClass` instead of `.css` to get your navbar sticking to the top. Bootstrap is providing a class for such things. If you are using Bootstrap, you could simply use `$cache.addClass('navbar-fixed-top')`. There are also more examples how you can handle your navbar. You may take a look into Bootstraps navbar docs, which you can find [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top).